# When broths and stocks can't be used interchangeably?

Tags: stock, broth

I have seen that sometimes stocks and broths can be used interchangeably in a recipe. I wonder - when can they NOT be used interchangeably?

Comment: This is way too cursory to be an answer, but if I were making any kind of a dish meant to be consumed cold or even tepid, then a stock that had a heavy gelatin content would be problematic, off the top of my head.

Answer (score 2):

From [WIKI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stock_(food)) they seem to be the same thing.

> Stock versus broth
>
> Many cooks and food writers use the terms broth and stock
>   interchangeably. In 1974, James Beard wrote emphatically that stock,
>   broth, and bouillon "are all the same thing".
>
> While many draw a distinction between stock and broth, the details of
>   the distinction often differ. One possibility is that stocks are made
>   primarily from animal bones, as opposed to meat, and therefore contain
>   more gelatin, giving them a thicker texture.[3] Another distinction
>   that is sometimes made is that stock is cooked longer than broth and
>   therefore has a more intense flavor. A third possible distinction is
>   that stock is left unseasoned for use in other recipes, while broth is
>   salted and otherwise seasoned and can be eaten alone.
>
> In Britain, "broth" can refer to a soup which includes solid pieces of
>   meat, fish, or vegetables, whereas "stock" would refer to the purely
>   liquid base. Traditionally, according to this definition, broth
>   contained some form of meat or fish; however, nowadays it is
>   acceptable to refer to a strictly vegetable soup as a broth.

A possible difference a broth is a byproduct of cooking and you make a stock.