# What is the difference in taste between stock and broth?

Tags: stock, broth, chicken-stock

I am under the impression that stock should not really taste like anything. It should smell nice and have a flavorful aroma, but the taste should be very neutral. The idea is that when you add stock to something else, it will accentuate and add depth. Like sour cream!

Broth should be flavorful and have taste and seasoning. It can be consumed as its own thing or have ingredients added to it to make a different dish such as a soup.

Am I right in this way of defining the difference in taste between the two?

Comment: Sorry its not a duplicate. I am not questioning how to USE it. I am questioning what each should TASTE like.

Comment: This answer suggests that there is no difference between broth and stock, unless you're using broth as a synonym for soup, and that people who say there is a difference can't agree on what the difference is: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/92741

Comment: I rolled back the edit -- I understand that you wanted to make the point that this is a different question, but too much formatting makes it more difficult to read :)

Comment: It is a bit difficult to say if it is a true duplicate or not, because your question is based on a wrong assumption. You are suggesting criteria for the difference between stocks and broths (which you say are based on taste, but in fact you tell us as much about use as about taste) and then ask if you are right. The problem is, there is no single accepted way to define the difference, people use all kinds of criteria. We already have that other question, and it also mixes up both taste and usage. Having such a jumble of opinions in a second place does not improve anything. That's why I closed.

Comment: Bold words make it difficult to read? Heh. I think I will go elsewhere with my questions... this place is a little too tyrannical for me.

Comment: It was more the ALLCAPS you added to the title that I found difficult, the bold was simply unnecessary. I am sorry you found my edit problematic, collaborative things like that are how StackExchange works (have you seen the [tour]?) -- but I understand that is not everybody's cup of tea. Again, I apologize if you found it unwelcoming.

Answer (score 0):

Even though I think they are essentially the same, based on general practices while you’re making stock you’ll end up with a high gelatin content, it will be thicker than a broth, as you tend to use mostly bones.

Stock is generally cooked and reduced longer compared to broth, so I would say stock would actually be more flavorful. However as you have noted, broth also involves seasoning and stock is on it’s own for later usage... They might have different flavor profiles based on how you cook and season them.